# is there a jquery ajax function that will call while it is waiting for error, success, or done?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was going to call an ajax funciton, and was looking through the api.  I was curious if there is a function that can be carried out while waiting for the success, error, done, etc to be be called.

I was hoping there was something like :

$.ajax({
...,
waiting: function(){
   //carry out some code
}
});

If it isnt in there already, it really should.  Its not as smart in my mind to have to carry that stuff before the ajax function was called...

waiting could easily carry out something such as displaying a loading gif or something like that.

Is there anything out there that does this sort of functionality?  I cant seem to find it.

Comment: What would be the difference between a waiting function and a function called after the ajax call?

Comment: In addition to yoshi's comment, I would say usually I put this kind of command **before** the call, so there is no race condition between the waiting command and the callback commands. Most ovious example is the 'loading...' message display and hiding at the end of the ajax call.

Comment: Yes, so with the different answers provided, i thought the beforeSend function would be the best way to accomplish it.  That way, in the example of a spinner, you would be booting it up right before the call, and then with the .done() command, have it fade out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"http://www.example.com/",
    beforeSend:function(){
        //show loading gif
    },
    success:function(resp){
        //handle response from server
        //hide or remove loading gif
    },
    error:function(msg){
        //show error message
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Any code that you have after your `$.ajax` call will actually start running immediately after the call starts. SO if you have something like this:

```
$ajax('someurl').done(function() { /*** success function ***/ });
someOtherFunctionCall();
```

`someOtherFunctoinCall()` will actually execute immediately after the ajax call starts and happen regardless of the success/failure of the call.

Comment: the downside of this, is that while it looks good here, you dont nessicarily see the relation between the ajax call and someOtherFunctionCall(); which is what i was trying

Answer (score 2):

You should display a loading GIF at the same time as you start the request. There's no real way to know the actual progress of the AJAX call, apart from the `readyState`, and that's what `onreadystatechange` is for (in plain JS, I don't know/care what its equivalent in jQuery is).

Comment: what about beforeSend: to create a spinner, then on Done() it will hide the spinner, or whatever the function beforeSend calls?

Comment: I guess you could do that, but why not just put the code to add the spinner immediately after the ajax function call?

Comment: Since it isnt lumped together, there is an idea that it would be accomplishing different tasks.  With that said, putting it in beforeSend there is a relation of the spinner to the ajax call instead of a function being fired after the ajax request

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to display a spinner until the ajax call is finished. Here's an example of how it can be done :

```
loading = {
    count: 0
};

loading.finish = function() {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count==0) this.$div.hide();
};

// 
loading.start = function() {
    this.count++;
    if (!this.$div) {
        var html = '<div style="position: fixed;z-index:100;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background: black;opacity: 0.6;">';
        html += '<table width=100% height=100%>';
        html += '<tr><td align=center valign=middle>';
        html += '<img src=img/loading.gif>';
        html += '</td></tr>';
        html += '</table></div>';
        this.$div=$(html);
        this.$div.prependTo('body');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (loading.count>0) loading.$div.show();
    }, 500);
};

// the function to call
askUrl = function(url, success) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                success(msg);
            }
            loading.finish();
        }
    };
    loading.start();
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
};
```

If you call askUrl and the servers doesn't answer in 500 ms, the screen is greyed and a spinner is displayed.

As it's a short code and it really depends on the desired result, I'm not sure this should be available in jQuery or even a plugin.

I got my gif spinner [here](http://ajaxload.info/).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use the beforeSend and complete functions for the ajax request..

```
$.ajax({
          .. Your ajax settings..
          success : function(result){
             // do what you want with data here
          },
          beforeSend : function(){
            // Show a ajax gif here
          },
          complete : function(){
            // Hide the ajax gif here
          }
    });
```

The beforeSend function is hit as soon as the ajax request is sent.. 
The complete function is triggered when it is out of the success function..
So you can notify the user as and when the request is done..